# Promises and ensuring readiness Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was just wondering if anyone has any good ideas about a "ensuring readiness" pattern in Node JS when using promises.  I have something like this, but I think the main problem with it is the fact that I think the .then(cb) for a promise actually overwrites the previous one, rather than chaining another handler...

```
  function awaitQueueCreation() {
     if (!q._queueURL) return whenQueueCreated;
     else return p.resolve(q._queueURL);
  }

  q.someQueueMethod = function(param) {
       awaitQueueCreation().then(function() {
           // do what this method is supposed to do...
       });
  };
```

How would you handle this type of thing?

Answer (score 2):

Adding an additional `.then()` handler onto the same promise just creates a second notification for the same promise.  It does not chain onto the previous `.then()` handler.  It does not overwrite any prior `.then()` handler.

So adding two `.then()` handlers just sequences two callbacks one after the other when the promise is fullfilled.

If the first `.then()` handler itself returns an unfullfilled promise, the second `.then()` handler is still called right away (it is not "chained" to the new unfullfilled promise).

To chain two promises, you must do something like this:

```
p.then(...).then(...)
```

Not:

```
p.then(...)
p.then(...)
```

Comment: In that case, it seems like my solution is optimal.

Comment: @JayPrime2012 - you haven't included enough of your code for me to understand or react to your actual code so I just tried to explain the concepts you mentioned.